# How to add a line break in php by concatenating strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, concatenation, line-breaks

I'm trying to add a line break when I concatenate some strings, but it's not working for me.
I have done it with "\ n" and with the PHP_EOL function and nothing.

```
 $data = $data." *Producto ".$aux.":* ".$nombre_producto." *cantidad:* ".$cantidad." *precio:* ".$precio_subtotal."".PHP_EOL;
```

This line of code is inside a for, adding concatenating that text string depending on the number of products in the array

Comment: Look at your HTML source, you'll (probably) see that the line breaks are there alright. If you're wanting to "see" the breaks on each line on screen, you need to use `<br>` or similar HTML markup.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that I am sending that information to the WhatsApp API and when I print it it does not have the line breaks.

Comment: PS: you can concat cleaner with `$data .= "more";` instead of doing `$data = $data."more";`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I've fixed it, added "%0a" at the end of each concatenation :)